# MATLAB: how to calculate the distribution of elements in matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix A with integer elements from 0 to N-1.

What I need to get is vector V of length N which for each position "i" will contain number of elements equal to "i" in matrix A.

For example:

```
N = 6

A:

0  0  1
1  2  3
3  5  0

V:

3 2 1 2 0 1 0
```

What is the efficient way to do this?

My real matrix is about 10K x 10K elements and N is about 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `v = histc(A(:), 0:(N-1))`. To get exactly your result, perform `v = v'`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [histc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/histc.html) (after [reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html) to convert to a vector)

> n = histc(x,edges) counts the number of values in vector x that fall
>   between the elements in the edges vector (which must contain
>   monotonically nondecreasing values). n is a length(edges) vector
>   containing these counts.

```
V = histc(reshape(A,1,[]), 0:(N-1) );
```